How exchange a column of a matrix by the multiplicative inverse of each element without rounding?
I need to exchange the elements of a column of a matrix by the multiplicative inverse of each element, but when the change is made, the number is rounded to zero. I am using Python.
I tried
matriz_atributos_max=np.array([
    [1500,12,64,24],
    [1800,12,128,18],
    [5000,20,128,10],
])

matriz_atributos_max_nova=matriz_atributos_max.copy()

for i in range(3):
  matriz_atributos_max_nova[i,0]=1/matriz_atributos_max[i,0]
matriz_atributos_max_nova

and I also tried
for i in range(3):
  matriz_atributos_max_nova[i,0]=round(1/matriz_atributos_max[i,0],6)
matriz_atributos_max_nova

and I also tried
matriz_atributos_max_nova[:,0]=1/matriz_atributos_max_nova[:,0]

The result is the same. The result is:
array([[  0,  12,  64,  24],
       [  0,  12, 128,  18],
       [  0,  20, 128,  10]])

but I need
array([[  0.000666,  12,  64,  24],
       [ 0.000555,  12, 128,  18],
       [  0.0002,  20, 128,  10]])


Check matriz_atributos_max.dtype : it is certainly an integer. You should generally specify dtype when calling np.array. It is safer. Otherwise the dtype is implicitly chosen from the input list.

try this the output provides precision to approximately 9 decimal places for the numbers displayed in scientific notation.
import numpy as np

matriz_atributos_max = np.array([
    [1500, 12, 64, 24],
    [1800, 12, 128, 18],
    [5000, 20, 128, 10],
], dtype=float)

reciprocal_first_column = 1 / matriz_atributos_max[:, 0]
matriz_atributos_max[:, 0] = reciprocal_first_column
print(matriz_atributos_max)

output
[[6.66666667e-04 1.20000000e+01 6.40000000e+01 2.40000000e+01]
 [5.55555556e-04 1.20000000e+01 1.28000000e+02 1.80000000e+01]
 [2.00000000e-04 2.00000000e+01 1.28000000e+02 1.00000000e+01]]


t didn't work for me to do it this way. I managed to do it like this:


```
    for i in range(3):
      new=1/matriz_atributos_max[i,0]
      matriz_atributos_max_nova[i,0]=float("%0.6f"%new)
    matriz_atributos_max_nova

```


what error did it throw out? It works fine for me

It wasn't working in the original file, but I opened a new file and used the same algorithm. In this new file it worked.
